# Orientation for Photo Captured by Camera Intent

Tags: android-camera-intent, android-contentresolver

I've captured several images from the Camera by launching it with an intent.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

When I display the image in a view after I capture it, it's orientation is always landscape, regardless of it being captured in portrait or otherwise.  I expect this based on what I've read on this forum.

However, when I look at it in the Gallery App or from the File Manager, it's displayed in it's correct orientation.

How does the Gallery App know what the capture orientation was?  I would like access to that same information, but it doesn't appear to be in the ExifInterace or the ContentResolver.

Comment: I've since noticed that after I restart the phone and restart my app, the images will display in the correct orientation in my app.  It has to be a full phone restart.  So it acts as though I don't have access to the orientation (via content resolver) until I reboot.  Why would this be?

Comment: Oh.  And it seems to primarily be a problem with Nexus Galaxy S (4.0.4).  This code works perfectly fine with the HTC Thunderbolt (2.3).